# Consulta SQL com lista em WHERE

Tags: php, sql

Tenho uma consulta que busca todas as id's de um BD. Faço um `WHILE` e coloco elas em `$retorno['dados']`. Como não tem nada separando elas, elas ficam todas juntas. Se retornar as id's `41, 45, 50`, eu recebo `414550`. Enfim, agora eu preciso fazer outra busca:

`SELECT * FROM restaurantes WHERE id=" id's que tenho em $retorno['dados'] "` e colocar em `WHILE` novamente, pois vou receber todos os dados de várias linhas.

Dei uma pesquisada, mas não consegui respostas. Qual seria a maneira de fazer essa busca?

Tenho duas Tabelas:

**Primeiro BD**

> ```
> id   |  idEmpresa  |   bairro
> 01   |      10     |  bairro 1
> 02   |      12     |  bairro 2
> 03   |      20     |  bairro 2
> 04   |      25     |  bairro 1
> ```

**Segundo BD**

> ```
> id   |  empresa 
> 10   |  empresa a 
> 12   |  empresa b 
> 20   |  empresa c 
> 25   |  empresa d
> ```

Eu recebo informação **bairro** e consulto quais empresas que atendem nesse bairro:

Recebendo por exemplo **bairro 1**, sei que a empresas com id **10 e 25** atendem nesse bairro. Logo preciso pegar no **Segundo BD** todas as informações das empresas com id **10 e 25**.

Essas são as duas querys que estou usando.

```
$retorno = array();
$retorno['dados'] = '';
$retorno['dados2'] = '';

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM endereco_atendimento WHERE bairro='Vila A'";
$buscar2 = $conexao->prepare($sql2);    
$buscar2->execute();
$buscar2->rowCount();
while($conteudo2 = $buscar2->fetchObject()){
    $retorno['dados2'] .= $conteudo2->idEmpresa;   
}
$lista = $retorno['dados2'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurantes WHERE id='$lista'";
$buscar = $conexao->prepare($sql);  
$buscar->execute();
$buscar->rowCount();
while($conteudo = $buscar->fetchObject()){
    $retorno['dados'] .= $conteudo->Nome;   
}
```

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o pretende com tudo isso.

Comment: @Edilson, editei a pergunta. Acho que ficou mais claro agora.

Comment: `select e.empresa from tbl1 as b join tbl2 as e on b.idEmpresa = e.id where b.bairro = "bairro 1";` podes usar o join para fazer isso, no final acabas simplesmente com a atributo `empresa` da segunda tabela. E no final acabas usando apenas um loop `while`.

Comment: @daltongonzaloFuentes: Ao acrescentar o nome do bairro, cuidado com _SQL Injection_.

Answer (score 2):

Pode colocar tudo em uma única consulta (com subconsulta).

```
-- código #1
SELECT Nome 
  from restaurantes
  where id in (SELECT idEmpresa
                 from endereco_atendimento
                 where bairro = 'nome bairro');
```

Answer (score -1):

Consegui solucionar. Deixo aqui a solução.

```
$retorno = array();
$retorno['dados'] = '';
$retorno['dados2'] = '';

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM endereco_atendimento WHERE bairro='Centro'";
$buscar2 = $conexao->prepare($sql2);    
$buscar2->execute();
$buscar2->rowCount();
while($conteudo2 = $buscar2->fetchObject()){
    $retorno['dados2'] .= "'".$conteudo2->idEmpresa."',";
}
$lista = trim($retorno['dados2'], ',');;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurantes WHERE id IN($lista)";
$buscar = $conexao->prepare($sql);  
$buscar->execute();
$buscar->rowCount();
while($conteudo = $buscar->fetchObject()){
    $retorno['dados'] .= $conteudo->Nome;   
}
```

Separei as id's da primeira consulta com aspas e virgula:

```
$retorno['dados2'] .= "'".$conteudo2->idEmpresa."',";
```

Tive que tirar a ultima virgula depois que a lista estava formada **'41','45',** para **'41','45'** pois essa ultima virgula gerava um erro. Na segunda consulta usei IN em WHERE:

```
"SELECT * FROM restaurantes WHERE id IN($lista)";
```

E deu certo!